# Is it likely that a fix for the RT3290 Bluetooth driver problem will be available for 14.04 and 15.10 in the near future?

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, 15.10, ralink

This [link](https://launchpad.net/~barracuda72/+archive/ralink/+files/rtbth-dkms_3.9.3-0ubuntu1~ppa3.tar.gz) appears to contain source code for the Bluetooth drivers for the Ralink/Mediatek radio device.  There are a number of posts and threads on Askubuntu regarding this issue - some going back to early 2014.  Thanks

Comment: Why do you ask all your questions in this form? Why not ask "How to get bluetooth working?

Comment: Because in trying to get it working over the past few days I've seen that the question in the form "How to get bluetooth working" has been asked many times without a successful outcome. Some of these threads go back a couple of years. The reason for the lack of a successful outcome, I believe is because the solution  requires developers to intervene - that is, it is beyond the capability of an average user. I am hoping that the form and content of my question will avoid similar answers which are offered in the many, many threads on the topic. Just trying to help.

Comment: And to add some of the information which I have uncovered.... Ubuntu 15.10, (kernel 4.2) loads rt3290.bin during startup. This bin file appears to only support the wifi component of the chipset. I have added a link to source code which I believe enables the Bluetooth. I am not clear on whether following the instructions associated with the code will conflict with the loaded rt3290.bin driver.

Comment: The code also requires tweaking for the version of the kernel used before compiling. I couldn't get it to compile - beyond my capability. I am hoping that the information in this question and subsequent comments allows someone (a developer) to narrow down the issue quickly and implement formal support in Ubuntu without users having to compile kernel patches assuming that they were to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have reported a bug: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1513705

But further investigation indicates that **this issue goes as far back as late 2012**. Other than the automated response requiring a further test and my subsequent information the bug tracker has had no activity.

A developer with Canonical - Anthony Wong was involved at the start ...

So unfortunately the answer appears to be "No..."

Answer (score 0):

I also was facing the same problem and I tried all the solution I could find and still could not solve it, most I was able to reach was that all the Bluetooth devices were showing but I was not able to connect to any of them.

But I just today finally found something that works and is very easy to install, it is located on github [rtbth-dkms](https://github.com/loimu/rtbth-dkms).

To Install,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:blaze/rtbth-dkms
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtbth-dkms
```

and then follow the `Init` commands below, your BlueTooth will work now, in case of any problem leave a comment,  I will be happy to help you.

Usage

```
# Init
sudo modprobe rtbth
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
hcitool dev # check

# Switch off
sudo rfkill block bluetooth

# Switch on
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth

# Shutdown
sudo pkill -2 rtbt
sudo rmmod rtbth
```

Comment: Thank you Suraj. It has been a while since I was on Stack Exchange. I had given up on bluetooth on my laptop. But its working now!